# Textarea vertical size and autosize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using a Jquery plugin named autosize (http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)
as to my textarea expands itself automatically (as am I typing) vertically, in case content exceeds its height (250px). Everything is fine with that. The problem is when I try to move the first textarea's content to a second one (the two textareas are identical) the second textarea's height remains 250px even if the first one's content had exceeded that limit. This movement is done as follows: send first content to MySQL, retrieve it and then present it to second textarea by:

```
$("#request_description").val(data1);
```

where data1 gets data from PHP corresponding variable which represents the initial textarea content and #request_description is the id of the second textarea. I tried to change height:250px to height:auto or to min-height:250px; however, nothing is done. Do you have any idea how may I oblige the second textarea adjusts its height to the proper content if the last has to exceed 250px?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple search on the plugin page show that "Autosize has no way of knowing when the value of a textarea has been changed through JavaScript".
As of this documentation, you should use `$("#request_description").val(data1)trigger('autosize.resize');`

Comment: Thank you very much.It did my job. You just forgot a dot before trigger